# Url.Action map a wrong link from Route attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is target controller and action:

```
[RoutePrefix("Editor")]
public class EditorController : Controller

[HttpGet]
    [Route("{id:int}")]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
```

Map method calling:

```
@Url.Action("Edit", "Editor", new { id = page.Id})
```

result:
/Editor?id=1

required result:
/Editor/1

Answer (score 8):

To achieve the result you want you have to use a route name:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{id:int}", Name = "EditorById")]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
```

Then in your view you would use Url.RouteUrl instead of Url.Action:

```
@Url.RouteUrl("EditorById", new { controller = "Editor", Id = 1, action = "Edit" })
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Does this mean I have to name all my actions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if you have enabled MVC AttributeRoutes?

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx

Comment: Yes, here is listing of RouteConfig.cs
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
            
        }

Comment: And yes, I was guided by this particular article when writing code.

Answer (score 0):

I just faced with same problem. When i fixed the links - editing is broken (form always redirects to the same page).

Here is solution:

A **link**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit my nice object", "Edit", new { id=item.Id })
```

A **form** in the view Edit.cshtml *(specifying Controller name is necessary!)*

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditConfirmed", "AppServers"))
```

The **actions** in the controller

```
public class AppServersController         
    [Route("edit/{id:int?}")]
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        // bla-bla
    }
    [Route("edit_confirmed")]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult EditConfirmed([Bind(Exclude = "Created,LastModified")] AppServerVM appServer)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View("Edit", appServer);
        // bla-bla
    }
}
```

Now both links and editing works.