# ActionLink generates wrong URL for Attribute Route

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015, attributerouting

I'm using attribute routing to override the URLs in my controller. I have two actions, with the only difference being the ID present on the second. The rest of the parameters are optional query parameters used for searching.

```cs
// RouteConfig.cs - I setup AttributeRoutes before any other mapped routes.
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

// Controllers/DeliveryController.cs
[Route("mvc/delivery")]
public ActionResult Delivery(string hauler, DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate, int? page)
{
    // ...
    return View(model);
}

[Route("mvc/delivery/{id}")]
public ActionResult Delivery(int id, string hauler, DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate, int? page)
{
    // ...
    return View("DeliverySelected", model);
}
```

Both routes work as expected when manually navigating to `/mvc/delivery` and `/mvc/delivery/1234/`, however links are generating incorrectly.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delivery", "Delivery", new { id = delivery.ID })
@Url.Action("Delivery", new { id = delivery.ID })
```

Either method generates links like the following, which triggers the first action instead of the second:

```
http://localhost:53274/mvc/delivery?id=1234
```

How can I generate the expected URL instead?

```
http://localhost:53274/mvc/delivery/1234
```

Comment: Here i've posted my solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39072017/1251169

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer, thanks to [this answer concerning ambiguous action methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10668537/93306). You can only have a maximum of 2 action methods with the same name in a controller.

I did have a third method in this case, that I left out since I thought it was unrelated:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("mvc/delivery")]
public ActionResult Delivery(DeliveryViewModel model)
```

Renaming my second action to `SelectDelivery(int id, /*...*/)` solved the issue.

Comment: I missed that. I didn't notice that the methods had the same name. But glad to hear it is resolved.

Comment: This solved it for me, had two methods with the same name, both GET.

Answer (score 1):

Since routes are order-sensitive, you need to use the [Order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.routeattribute.order(v=vs.118).aspx) parameter to ensure they are executed in the right order.

```
// Controllers/DeliveryController.cs
[Route("mvc/delivery", Order = 2)]
public ActionResult Delivery(string hauler, DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate, int? page)
{
    // ...
    return View(model);
}

[Route("mvc/delivery/{id}", Order = 1)]
public ActionResult Delivery(int id, string hauler, DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate, int? page)
{
    // ...
    return View("DeliverySelected", model);
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it made no difference. I also tried moving the second action to be first in the file, removed all the optional parameters from both actions, and commented out the other `MapRoute`s, but none of the above has helped.

Answer (score -1):

you can use following to solve it

```
    [Route("mvc/delivery/{hauler}/{startdate?}/{enddate}/{page?}")]
    public ActionResult Delivery(string hauler, DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate, int? page)
    {
        // ...
        return View(model);
    }

    [Route("mvc/delivery/{id:int}/{hauler}/{startdate?}/{enddate}/{page?}")]
    public ActionResult Delivery(int id, string hauler, DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate, int? page)
    {
        // ...
        return View("DeliverySelected", model);
    }
```