# Url.Action delivers wrong result when RouteAttribute is used

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5.2

I've got the following scenario:

```
[RoutePrefix("MvcApi/MyData")]
public class MyDataController : Controller
{
    [Route("GetAsSelectionListBySiteId/{siteId}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetAsSelectionListBySiteId(int siteId)
    {
        var items = await IoC.Instance.GetInstance<IDataProvider>().GetBySiteIdAsync(ParallelDataAccessor, siteId);
        return Json(items.Select(s => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(s.Identifier, s.DisplayName)).ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public static class Routes
    {
        public static RouteValueDictionary GetAsSelectionListBySiteId(int siteId)
        {
            return new RouteValueDictionary()
                .AddReturn(nameof(siteId), siteId)
                .AddReturn("area", "MvcApi");
        }
    }
}
```

When i use

`@Url.Action("GetAsSelectionListBySiteId", "MyData", MyDataController.Routes.GetAsSelectionListBySiteId(5))`

in a view this will render as

`MvcApi/MyData/GetAsSelectionListBySiteId?siteId=5 <- 404 error`

when i do in fact need it like this

`MvcApi/MyData/GetAsSelectionListBySiteId/5 <- 200 ok`

Is this a bug in @Url.Action? Is there a way to influence it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When generating URL your best options is to always use the route names because this way you do not get into the subtleties of the algorithm used to select the route that will be used to generate the URL.

My advice if for you not to use Url.Action and instead use Url.RouteUrl which allows you to specify the name of the route that should be used to construct the URL.

By always using route names you also make your code more robust to changes, for example, you can add new routes without having to worry that they might break your existing code for URL generation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26365464/url-action-map-a-wrong-link-from-route-attribute

Comment: Resharper offers no support to do Routejumps however. So i do dislike it in a way, because refactoring/codenavigation will be worse